# simple test in Jquery isn't working. green square doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so the green square is suppose to show when your mouse is on the red square, but it doesn't. Here is the code:

```
 <html>                                                                  
     <head>                                                                  
         <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">                                         
         <!--
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $("a").bind("mouseover", 
                function(){
                    $("b").css("display", "block");
               });

               $("a").bind("mouseout", 
                function(){
                    $("b").css("display", "none");
               });
             });
         -->                                   
         </script>                                                               
         </head>                                                                 
     <body>                                                                  
        <div class="a" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>
        <div class="b" style="display: none; background-color: #00ff00; height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>

     </body>                                                                 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a dot before each selector to form a *class* selector:

```
$(".a").bind("mouseover", 
                function(){
                ...
```

Your code can be reduced to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".a").hover(function() {
        $(".b").toggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/EkA6p/1/

Answer (score 0):

Should be $(".a"). the selector needs a period. Where if you had id="a" then you would use ("#a"), but just doing $("a") will actually select all links i.e. `<a href="">`

http://jsfiddle.net/hZL94/

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the class `.a` `.b`

```
<script type="text/javascript">                              
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".a").bind("mouseover", 
        function(){
            $(".b").css("display", "block");
       });

       $(".a").bind("mouseout", 
        function(){
            $(".b").css("display", "none");
       });
     });                             
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's becasue you try to select the `<a>` and `<b>` elements, instead of the `<div class="a">` and `<div class="b">` elements. `$('.a')` instead of `$('a')`. See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/F3vVm/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".a").bind("mouseover", function() {
        $(".b").css("display", "block");
    });

    $(".a").bind("mouseout", function() {
        $(".b").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<html>                                                                  
     <head>                                                                  
         <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

         <script type="text/javascript">                                         
             $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#a").bind("mouseover", 
                function(){
                    $("#b").css("display", "block");
               });

               $("#a").bind("mouseout", 
                function(){
                    $("#b").css("display", "none");
               });
             });                         
         </script>                                                               
         </head>                                                                 
     <body>                                                                  
        <div id="a" style="background-color: #ff0000; height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>
        <div id="b" style="display: none; background-color: #00ff00; height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>

     </body>       
     </html>
```